# Using Google Webmaster Tools "Parameters"

Tags: query-string, sitemap, google-search-console

I have recently indexed my website.

Google has indexed the main site as:
**www.site.com/?ref=old**

Is it possible in my Google Webmaster Tools that I can get Google to ignore:
*www.site.com/?ref=old* but still index *www.site.com*?

How do I achieve this?

Bit scared of using the URL Parameters option.

Many thanks for any pointers here :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could place this in your old site:

```
<?php
header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
header( "Location: http://www.yoursite.com/" );
exit(0);
?>
```

Or an .htaccess file should do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^ref=old
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.yoursite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

(not tested)

However the GWT Parameters is also a good option to let it not crawl the ?ref=old